# Asking about a clarification of a rather strange notation of a Yee Grid used for discretizing Maxwell's Equations

Tags: computational-physics, maxwell-equations, discrete

The thesis I am following requires me to discuss a rather strange formulation of a Yee grid used to discretize Maxwell's equations in order to solve them numerically mentioned in a research paper. The paper in question can be found in the following link:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/001046559290026U

Now the problem I have begins with the definition of the grid itself. The paper begins by introducing the grid as shown in the image below

[image]

As you can notice, the grid has a multitude of nodes noted n (no idea why no $i,j,k$ index has been assigned to each node, something like $n_{i,j,k}$). The problems begin however with numbering of the nodes as defined by the authors themselves:

[image]

The issue here is on different levels:

1. The nodes are not indexed (as I mentioned before), making it really hard to keep up with any numbering
2. For the value of the index n, there are jumps since $M_v = I$ and $M_w = I\times J$ are supposedly large numbers, so how come can we have $n$ taking all the natural number values from $1$ to $I\times J\times K$ (it does not even make sense for n to be equal to $1$ at one point since $i$,$j$ and $k$ begin from 2 anyway, and by replacing $i$,$j$ and $k$ with 2 as their smallest value we get $n_{min} = 1+ M_u + M_v + M_w = 2+I+I\times J$)?
3. Another issue is the incrementation of the $E$ and $B$ which do not make much sense to me. For instance, in **Fig.2** we can watch the $E$ field go from $E_{u,n}$ to $E_{u,n+M_{v}}$. Is it just me or the field should have a clearer indexing? also, shouldn't the step be $1$ instead of $M_v$? I am completely lost.

Any help or input would be much much much appreciated since this cornerstone concept has been given in the strangest way possible. Or maybe I am dumb.

Anyway, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Using  $N$ indexes to identify points in a discrete $N$-dimensional grid is usually convenient. However, it is perfectly possible to use a one-dimensional index provided an explicit correspondence between the finite set of $N$-dimensional indexes and the finite set of one-dimensional values has been established.

Comment: Theoretically I imagine myself understanding your valuable comment since my 1st remark was the easiest point to understand among the 3. 
Do you have some input concerning the other two?
Thank you infinitely.

Comment: They are related. It doesn't matter how you name the index or what is the starting value of $i,j,k$. What matters is that you have a finite number of grid points and you can always call them $1,2,3,...$. I agree that three indexes are more clear than one, but it is always possible to encode them into one index.

Comment: Sure thing. But the indexing does not move by 1 step each time according to the author's definition right?
Or am I missing something?
what I am trying to do is map the indexing of the author to an $i,j,k$ indexing pattern as a first step.